# taurus tests running out of order?

Tags: jmeter, taurus

I am new to taurus testing. I have a set of tests inside of a taurus project. [image]

Within the scenario 1300_Azuresubscriptions.yaml I have the following list of labels:

```
0100-Authorization
1300_ListAzureSubscriptions
1310_CreateAzureSubscriptions
1320_UpdateAzureSubscriptions
1330_FetchAzureSubscription
1340_CreateAVWGateway
1341_CreateVirtualWanSite
1342_ListVirtualWanSites
1343_UpdateVirtualWanSite
1344_FetchVirtualWanSite
1345_DeleteVirtualWanSite
1346_DeleteAVWGateway
1350_DeleteAzureSubscription
1351_ListADSubscription
1352_CreateAzureSubscriptions
1353_FetchADSubscription
1354_ValidateADSubscriptions
1355_GetADGroups
1356_ADSyncConfigurations
1357_ADSync
1358_CheckADCLientCreation
1359_DeleteADSubscription
1360_CheckADCLientDeletion
1361_ListAzureSubscriptionsWithInvalidAuthHeader
1362_ListAzureSubscriptionsWithNoAuthHeader
1363_CreateAzureSubscriptionsWithInvalidAuthHeader
1364_CreateAzureSubscriptionsWithNoAuthHeader
1365_UpdateAzureSubscriptionsWithInvalidAuthHeader
1366_UpdateAzureSubscriptionsWithNoAuthHeader
1367_FetchAzureSubscriptionWithInvalidAuthHeader
1368_FetchAzureSubscriptionWithNoAuthHeader
1369_CreateAVWGatewayWithInvalidAuthHeader
1370_CreateAVWGatewayWithNoAuthHeader
```

However when I run `bzt test-cases/1300_AzureSubscriptions.yaml`, only the following list of labels are actually getting tested:

```
0100-Authorization
1300_ListAzureSubscriptions
1310_CreateAzureSubscriptions
1320_UpdateAzureSubscriptions
1330_FetchAzureSubscription
1340_CreateAVWGateway
1341_CreateVirtualWanSite
1342_ListVirtualWanSites
1343_UpdateVirtualWanSite
1344_FetchVirtualWanSite
1345_DeleteVirtualWanSite
1346_DeleteAVWGateway
1350_DeleteAzureSubscription
1351_ListADSubscription
1352_CreateAzureSubscriptions
1353_FetchADSubscription
1354_ValidateADSubscriptions
1355_GetADGroups
1356_ADSyncConfigurations
1357_ADSync
1358_CheckADCLientCreation
1359_DeleteADSubscription
1363_CreateAzureSubscriptionsWithInvalidAuthHeader
1364_CreateAzureSubscriptionsWithNoAuthHeader
1365_UpdateAzureSubscriptionsWithInvalidAuthHeader
1366_UpdateAzureSubscriptionsWithNoAuthHeader
1367_FetchAzureSubscriptionWithInvalidAuthHeader
1368_FetchAzureSubscriptionWithNoAuthHeader
1369_CreateAVWGatewayWithInvalidAuthHeader
1370_CreateAVWGatewayWithNoAuthHeader
```

Why isn't it running the labels 1360-1362? I don't understand the problem. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm voting to close my own question because it contains private information. It's a liability.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue was the indentation in the yaml. I would recommend that if you're running these tests you'd better install a linter to check your yaml formatting. One tab off and the error is invisible. It just ignores the tests.

Answer (score 0):

[Taurus](https://gettaurus.org/) is just a wrapper for underlying load and functional testing tools, if something is not executed there could be various reasons for this, for example:

1. The particular request is not enabled in YAML configuration file
2. The underlying test executor is failing on attempt to run the particular request
3. There is a lack of test data for the requests

Check out *bzt.log* file and any logs generated by the underlying tool. By default Taurus uses [JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) executor so if it's your case the reason could be found in `jmeter.log` file (it also worth checking `jmeter.out` and `jmeter.err` for any suspicious entries)

More information: [Navigating your First Steps Using Taurus](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/navigating-your-first-steps-using-taurus)

You can also reach out to Taurus developers, maintainers and users at [Taurus support forum](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/codename-taurus/)